# Is the order of columns on the MATCH() clause important?

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

Here is my query:

```
. . . WHERE MATCH ( col1, col2 ) AGAINST ( :q )
```

Now I want to know, is there any difference between query above and this one?

```
. . . WHERE MATCH ( col2, col1 ) AGAINST ( :q )
```

---

Actually my tests say no, there isn't any difference between them, I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No difference.  But you do need `FULLTEXT(col1, col2)` (in either order).